# How to call a view from the view?

Tags: android

I am a new developer for Android.
I wanna know about View transitions.

For my application, it has 5 screens that can shift each other.

In order word, Screen1 -> Screen2 <--> Screen3 <--> Screen4 -> Screen5.

How to make this screen transition on Android ?

Please share the knowledge.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, set them up as separate activities, using BACK to move back in the stack and something in your UI to move forward.

If that is unacceptable, try `ViewFlipper` to switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use intent to move from one screen to other.

```
Intent i = new Intent(firstscreen.this,secondscreen.class)
startactivity(i);
```